# Java TreeMap without GNU GDL

Tags: java, treemap

I am looking for a source-code of a TreeMap without GNU License.

I need this because I need a TreeMap which can handle with Entrys (example: putEntry(Entry aEntry). My program will be used commercialy.

Thanks in advanced

i dont search library...!

the code in the answer is not what i want. than i copy the entry. i will recycle a entry

Comment: So basically, "gimme teh codez" (Although not in the way it's usually seen...)

Comment: What's wrong with the built in `TreeMap`? Sure, there's no `putEntry()` method specifically, but it's beyond trivial to break the entry down into its key and value and just use the `put()` method! I can't see why you're going to the trouble of finding a 3rd party alternative at all...

Comment: i must recycle a map, the problem is, if i say put(k,v) than it will copy the entry. i dont want copy a entry.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Created especially for you.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class TreeMapWithoutGNULicense<K, V> extends TreeMap<K, V> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3069492680223110767L;

    public boolean putEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> entry) {
        return super.entrySet().add(entry);
    }
}
```

I'm thinking of licensing it as beerware.

**Update**

[SO leaves me no choice](https://stackexchange.com/legal): it's got to be the [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/). Please refrain from sending me beer.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not your choice what licence to use - according to http://stackexchange.com/legal anything you post on SO (or any other Stack Exchange site) is automatically [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/)...

Comment: that is not the solution.i have a problem with the garbage collector so i have to recycle a map.  super.put will create a new Entry Object and the old one will be sweep by gc

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But i have a big problem. i cant change the key from a entry in entrySet ;(

Comment: Entry keys are immutable. Listen, Java's collection/type system is more than rich enough. Why don't you just create a treemap that does exactly what you want?

Comment: i have never done this before and my problem is to fix the red and black tree after insertion. i dont know how i have to rotate and how to rotate.

Comment: if i use a hashmap and i add the entryset a new entry, will the entry get hashed again? or is it impossible to add a entrySet from a hashmap a entry beocuse of the buckets?


ok, there will be an UnsupportedOperationException... there is no option to add a entry and change the key i see...